# VS Code is not aware of the code generated by c#9 source generators

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, .net-5, sourcegenerators

I have a console application that references a project which holds a source generator.

Everything is working fine, the code runs and does what is expected but VS Code is not aware of the code generated.

I have in my project a class

```
public partial class Foo
{
    public partial int GetNum();
}
```

and in the referenced project I generate the implementation for this partial method:

```
public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var source = @"namespace MyNamespace
        {
            public partial class Foo
            {
                public partial int GetNum() => 23;
            }
        }";

        if (source != null)
        {
            context.AddSource("generated.cs", source);
        }
    }
```

The code builds and runs fine, but VS Code is not happy:
[image]

How can I tell VS Code to consider the generate code?

Comment: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues Report to the developers if no existing report is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it by setting the generator project to netstandard2.0

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/1934#issuecomment-706329123

but go to definition is not working

Comment: Go to Definition not working is a known issue.